# Swift Compile Times - Should the `final` keyword increase or decrease compile time?

Tags: swift, compilation

Would explicitly declaring classes `final` and making sure `private` stuff is annotated as such increase or decrease compile times? I understand how it affects runtime by reducing dynamic dispatch.

Anecdotally, I've tried this on a medium sized project (and turned on the Xcode defaults to print compile times), and the compile time surprisingly increased (by 8 seconds). Shouldn't it be easier to understand how all the code fits together with hints that eliminate subclasses?

Comment: Note sure why `final` should increase compilation time. With `final`, fewer things are legal than without it, and so the compiler has to check that code which `final` makes illegal is not present. `private` may make autocompletion work faster, but should not have a large impact on compile time.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been flagged as a duplicate. The referenced question seems to be is unaware of the runtime performance benefits, whereas I'm interested in compiler performance. The useful bit I can pull from the linked answer is "[t]his allows the compiler to safely elide dynamic dispatch indirection," but that doesn't exactly indicate an increase or decrease in compilation time.

Comment: I agree, this does not seem like a duplicate. Should be reopened.